# How to use module function in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I exports a function in *load.js* and want to use this in my router file.(Honestly I confuse this terms because I'm starter of node js).

load.js:

```
import demo from "./ml.js";

exports.loadData = async function() {
    var result = [];
    try {
        if(window.localStorage.getItem("imgcropped") !== null) {
            var image = document.getElementById('img-load');
            result = await demo(image);

            return result;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('ML load error: ' + e);
    }
}
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');
var load = require('./public/js/load.js');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/scripts', express.static('node_modules'));
app.use(cors({
    credentials: true
}));

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

const server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Express server has started on port 3000");
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('home', {
    });
});

app.get('/load', function(req, res){
    //var idx = load.loadData(); <- That I want.
    res.render('load', {
    });
});
```

And I added

```
var load = require('./path/to/load.js');
```

But It doesn't working. Even no error message in pm2 log. Just it show me 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED' in Chrome.
Can I use `load.loadData` function in *server.js*? Or please let me know.

+++
I'm work on AWS ec2. When I connect load.js to load.ejs directly, the function loadData is worked well. (Without using exports.module, just execute `loadData()` in load.js)

Comment: Yes, you can use `load.loadData()`.  That function call will return a promise that you can use `await` or `.then()` on to get the resolved value.  But, `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` is something entirely different.  You will have to show us what exact code or request is generating that error before we can help you with that.

Comment: @jfriend00 I modified my code. Please confirm this post above. I'm work on this server on AWS ec2

Comment: Don't mix ES6 `import` syntax with the `exports` object

Comment: `load.js` is accessing `window` and `document`, which don't exist in node. What are you trying to do in regard to load.js?